# how to tweet using oauth token and secret in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

i can successfully redirect from valid twitter credential and i found this much parameter

```
[session_id] => ef19487c18256fcc539347e339e800bb
[ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
[last_activity] => 1380864503
[user_data] => 
[tw_access_token] => Array
    (
        [oauth_token] => XXXXXXXXXXX
        [oauth_token_secret] => XXXXXXXXX
        [user_id] => 19297XXXXX
        [screen_name] => XXXYYYZZZ
    )

[tw_status] => verified
```

now i want to tweet using this account, as array says i have oauth_token & secret.

if anybody develop such thing let me direct from this stage.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update

Comment: @stormdrain i know the parameters tweet process i want a dynamic consumer key and consumer secrets of account while login with twitter. so i can change my numbers and tweet to chooses account.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The key and secret are in the response you posted. Directions on posting a tweet are in the link I provided.

Comment: @stormdrain i am using tmhoauth to tweet on user account for that i need 4 thing consumer key, consumer secret key, access token, access secret token.  i have last two how to get first two??

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2530

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're using tmhoauth below is the format for tweeting.

```
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
  'consumer_key' => 'your-consumer-key',
  'consumer_secret' => 'consumer-secret',
  'token' => 'your access token',
  'secret' => 'token secret',
));
$response = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/update'), array(
 'status' => 'Test message '
));
```

The token and token secret are available right at the bottom of the page where you've created your application. (http://dev.twitter.com/apps)

Comment: If you're trying to get the oauth_token and secret, do something like this
    $access_token=$_SESSION['tw_access_token'];
    echo $access_token['oauth_token'];
    echo $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];


I am wondering why you'd do that when you've your token and secret at the application settings page.

Comment: boss i am not taking my secrets.. i want users app secret while they login. so they can tweet my site contents without need of popup..